# GitHub for Windows push/pull, results in Eclipse infinite refresh loop

Tags: eclipse, git, github, refresh, github-for-windows

Whenever I pull or push using GitHub for Windows or PowerShell, Eclipse will start an infinite loop of refreshing projects. (I then have to use the task manager to quit Eclipse and stop the java process.)

I have unchecked all auto refresh options in eclipse (searched for refresh in preferences) but that does not seem to help. 
I am using Windows 7 64, and I have the same issue in both Eclipse Juno and Kepler.

Any idea what may be causing this?

Comment: I can see why this might happen for pulls, since you would be updating your working copy (similar thing happens in Visual Studio, it has to reload any open projects), but it's very strange that this would happen with a push, are you sure about that?

Comment: When I tested it again now, push and pull both worked through PowerShell. And both faild when using the "Sync" button in GitHub for Windows app. And also if I rolled back some commits and den hit the discard all changes, it would some times result in the same issue. It has also happened when first changing branch in Eclipse then open GitHub app, and when GitHub app says refreshing... the problem some times occur as well. So it seems like it has something to do with the Sync or Auto-refresh stuff in GitHub app.

Comment: I see similar problems. Adding about 10MB for a new project GitHub for Windows (GUI) seems to loop. I just add the files, open GitHub for Windows, select the new project and then it loops. It stops looping, shows the commit box. I try to write something there and then it loops again.

Comment: That was unfair. It does not totally hang. It just takes about a quarter of an hour for the character to reach the form. And then it does not loop any more. Until I enter the next character. ;-) -- There must be some rather simple mistake in the code behind this.

Comment: I was able to get work around this by (1) Deleting the local rep, (2) clone again from github, (3) just add one directory+one file, (4) adding the rest of the files. The commit did not work, but clicking sync seems to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse Neon (where there was a similar problem), what helped there was to go to:

```
Eclipse -> Preferences -> General -> Startup and Shutdown
```

And turn off `RSE UI`.